# The login views are not being rendered error cant GET/login occurs nodejs

Tags: node.js, ejs

```
const app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

const staticPath = path.join(__dirname, 'public');

// Use the express.static middleware to serve static files
app.use(express.static(staticPath));
// Login route
app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {

  const { username, password } = req.body;

  try {
    const user = await User.loginUser(username, password);
    req.session.user = user;
    res.redirect('/');
  } catch (error) {
    res.render('/login', { error: error.message });
  }
});

// Register route
app.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
  const { username, email, password } = req.body;

  try {
    await User.registerUser(username, email, password);
    res.redirect('/login');
  } catch (error) {
    res.render('register', { error: error.message });
  }
});
```

this code is not rendering any views
not console errors

i tried changing the routes that i can possibly fing the change it to the rot directory still it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

> cant GET /login

Because there's no endpoint which handles a GET request for `/login`.  You're only handling a POST request:

```
app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
  //...
});
```

Basically, you missed a step.  You wrote the code which accepts the form submission from the login page, but not the code which initially shows the login page in the first place.  That would be a GET request, for example:

```
app.get('/login', async (req, res) => {
  res.render('/login');
});
```

Comment: thanks for the update but a new error has occurred Error: Failed to lookup view "/login" in views directory  for which i added  app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views')) as seen in many solutions but it doesnt work

Comment: @Abhiram: Maybe the view name used should be `'login'` instead of `'/login'`?  You seem to be using the two interchangeably, but the tooling may not allow that.